Compute $\lim_{t\to\infty}\int_0^{\infty}\frac{e^{-tx}\sin x}{x}\;dx$
Let be consider the function $$I(t):=\int _0 ^ \infty \frac{e^{-tx}\sin x}{x}\;dx.$$ I must prove that $\lim_{t\to\infty} I(t)=0$ for $t>0$.

I want to use the DCT. We have that $$\lim_{t\to \infty} f(t,x)=0,$$ where $f(t,x)=\frac{e^{-tx}\sin x}{x}.$

My problem is finding the dominant function.
I've seen some people do it this way:
It's clear that the function $f(\cdot, x)$ is differentiable for all $t\in\mathbb{R}$ and for all $x>0$, then we have that $$|f_t(t,x)|=|e^{-tx}\sin x|\le e^{-tx}\le e^{-rx}$$ for all $t\ge r > 0$ and for all $x>0$. Since $e^{-rx}\in L^1((0,\infty))$we have that $$I'(t)=-\int_0^\infty e^{-tx}\sin x\;dx$$ from which we have that $$I'(t)=-\frac{1}{1+t^2}.$$ Then we have that $$I(t)=A-\arctan t$$ for all $t>0$, where $A\in \mathbb{R}$. Now $$\lim_{t\to\infty} I(t)=A-\frac{\pi}{2}$$
If I proved that $\lim_{t\to\infty}I(t)=0$ then we would have that $A=\frac{\pi}{2}$. What am I doing wrong?

It's not clear what you're doing

$A=I(0)=\int_{0}^{+\infty} \frac{\sin x}x dx$

@SineoftheTimeMy problem is to compute the $\lim_{t\to \infty} f(t,x)$.

you have computed it and found it's $0$

Split the integral at $x=2$ and use $e^{-tx}\le e^{-t}e^{-tx/2}$ to estimate the integral on $(2, \infty)$.

@SineoftheTimeI cannot use the value of that integral.

If you want to use the DCT, why not just use $g(x) = e^{-x} \sin(x) / x$? It's integrable and dominates $f(x,t)$ for $t>1$.

If you want to us DCT, why are you evaluating the integral? The last sentence does not make sense, since that's what you want to prove

If the condition has changed and you don't need to apply the DCT anymore, $$\int_0^{\infty}\frac{e^{-tx}\sin x}{x}dx=\arctan\frac1t=\frac\pi2-\arctan t$$

Am I missing something? $$|I(t)|\le \int _0 ^ \infty \left|\frac{e^{-tx}\sin x}{x}\right|\;dx\le \int _0 ^ \infty e^{-tx}\;dx$$

To use DCT, shouldn't the dominant function be a function  only of $x$?

@SineoftheTime You can show $I(t) \to 0$ by bounding the terms for each $t$ without having to use the DCT.

Perfect! No need for DCT

@TrevorNorton yeah but OP said "I want to use the DCT"

@SineoftheTime: not any more they don't!

+1 even if I think OP should clarify the problem
